# Compress image file from AsyncFileUpload

Tags: c#, compression, asyncfileupload

Is it possible to compress images upon upload directly from `AsyncFileUpload`? If yes, can you guide me how?

For example: I have a user that uploads an image `.jpeg` with size `1200x1600 (5MB)` and I want to compress it into a `600x800 (1MP~2MB)` file. As much as possible I have to do this on client side just before I upload it to server.

Thank you.

Comment: _Is it possible to.._ Did you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library. I think you will find your solution there.

Comment: I want to compress the image before upload. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Did you look at the examples? What are you trying? Why this approach can't do what you want?

Comment: Can I compress it on client side?

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak : Are you sure you want to use ZIP? From your question it seems you want to *resize* your image instead. And ZIP won't do anything to JPG

Answer (score 1):

On HTML5 browser, you can use the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10334170/529282), otherwise you're stuck with requiring your client to use a plugin ([Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088966/i-need-to-resize-images-upon-upload-in-java-struts-how-to-do-this), [Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431120/flash-upload-image-resize-client-side), [Silverlight](http://programmerpayback.com/2010/01/21/use-silverlight-to-resize-images-and-increase-compression-before-uploading/)) etc.

Comment: I think this is the one I am looking for but how can I integrate this on `AsyncFileUpload` of asp.net?

Comment: Either subclass or extend the selecting method so instead of selecting the original file it would select the resized image.

Comment: Ok.. How can I do that? Do the user have to upload the image to server before compression?

Comment: No no, the point is to resize (not compressing, JPG is already compressed) before uploading. In the answer for HTML5, notice the end of the sample code is : var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); So just point that dataurl to the AsyncFileUpload

Comment: I just want to maximize the space of my servers. I want to compress/resize the file. If that is how you call it then thats it.

Comment: Now the actual purpose of resizing on client isn't as much as saving space in the server, but in reducing the bandwidth requirement of both the server and client. If you don't care about the bandwidth, just use the regular upload and tell your server to resize the incoming images. On the other hand, if you want to also save the bandwidth, the you just have to pick one of the method I give (HTML5 works best unless you somehow need to support IE6)

Comment: Though it is a local system, I also consider the bandwidth since we multiple user. The traffic of transactions are distinctively heavy.

Comment: Ok, so use one of the method I propose. All those method create a local copy of the image, which you'll pass to AsynFileUpload

Comment: Ok let me try this. Thanks. I'll marked this as answered if it work.